Value does not live long enough in main
While writing some Rust, I've run into an issue with this code:
fn main() {
    let session = Connection::new_session().unwrap();

    let manager = DBusManager::new(&session);

    let tray = ksni::TrayService::new(VariaTray {
        visible: false,
        manager: manager.clone(),
    });

    tray.run();
}

I'm making a program that runs a tray icon and communicates with another program over D-Bus, but I'm getting this error when I try to compile it.
error[E0597]: `session` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:50:36
   |
48 |     let session = Connection::new_session().unwrap();
   |         ------- binding `session` declared here
49 |
50 |     let manager = DBusManager::new(&session);
   |                   -----------------^^^^^^^^-
   |                   |                |
   |                   |                borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                   argument requires that `session` is borrowed for `'static`
...
58 | }
   | - `session` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.

I'm unsure how to resolve this issue. It seems like it shouldn't be causing this error since the value is dropped at the end of the program, but I am new to Rust, so I don't know its behavior that well yet. Could I get some help?
(I am using the dbus-rs and ksni crates in this code, along with a custom struct for wrapping the D-Bus operations.)

What's DBusManager? It doesn't appear in the docs for the dbus crate…

TrayService seem to require a 'static lifetime. It may be worth investigating what would happen if you change ksni's code to remove that bound, and if it works, open an issue.

You yourself likely defined DBusManager to contain a &'static Connection. Then when passing a temporary reference into it, Rust correctly complains about it.
Here are some alternatives I would suggest:

Change DBusManager to take an owned Connection, and directly pass it in instead of a reference.

If you still need immutable access to the original connection in places other than the DBusManager, accept an Arc<Connection> in DBusManager.



I think this is too vague and too much full of assumptions to be a good and acceptable answer. That said, I agree with the points you make.
